# Android: Updating ListView

Tags: android, listview, simplecursoradapter

Well, I have read almost 50 links related to this question, but my code still not working.

I have a Custom adapter which extends SimpleCursorAdapter class, and I use that adapter to fill the ListView on onCreate method

```
private void populateListView()
{
    String[] from = new String[] { SchemaHelper.TASK_DESCRIPTION, SchemaHelper.TASK_CREATED_ON, SchemaHelper.TASK_ID };

    int[] to = new int[] {R.id.lv_row_description, R.id.lv_row_created_on};

    tasksCursor = schemaHelper.getTasks();

    startManagingCursor(tasksCursor);

    tasksAdapter = new TasksAdapter(this, R.layout.tasks_listview_row, tasksCursor, from, to);

    setListAdapter(tasksAdapter);
}
```

The App is a simple task manager, I want to update the ListView contents when the user submits a new task without calling setListAdapter() again.

I have tried notifyDataSetChanged (running on ui thread), invalidate, requery(deprecated)... almost everything.

I'm doing something wrong?

EDIT:
This is the method where I add a new task to the database

```
private void addTask(String description)
{
    String message = "";

    schemaHelper.open();

    if(schemaHelper.isAlreadyInDatabase(description))
    {
        message = getString(R.string.task_already_exists);
    }
    else
    {
        message = getString(R.string.task_succesfully_added);

        schemaHelper.insertTask(description);

        populateListView();

        newTask.setText("");
    }

    schemaHelper.close();

    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

ADAPTER CLASS:

```
private class TasksAdapter extends SimpleCursorAdapter
{
    private LayoutInflater layoutInflater;

    private Cursor cursor;

    public TasksAdapter(Context context, int layout, Cursor c, String[] from, int[] to)
    {
        super(context, layout, c, from, to);

        cursor = c;

        cursor.moveToFirst();

        layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {
        if(cursor.getPosition() < 0)
        {
            cursor.moveToFirst();
        }
        else
        {
            cursor.moveToPosition(position); // Here throws the error
        }

        View row = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.tasks_listview_row, null);

        TextView description = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.lv_row_description);

        TextView createdOn = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.lv_row_created_on);

        description.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(SchemaHelper.TASK_DESCRIPTION)));

        createdOn.setText(getString(R.string.added_on) + " " + TaskHelper.formatDateWithSuffix(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(SchemaHelper.TASK_CREATED_ON))));

        return row;
    }
}
```

Comment: How/where do you add the new tasks?

Answer (score 0):

i dont know much of the taskCursor and taskAdapter but i used ArrayAdapter i guess, well have a look in my code and take your own conclusions.

```
               //LISTVIEW database CONTATO
    ListView user = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvShowContatos);
    //String = simple value ||| String[] = multiple values/columns
    String[] campos = new String[] {"nome", "telefone"};

    list = new ArrayList<String>();
    Cursor c = db.query( "contatos", campos, null, null, null, null, "nome" + " ASC ");
    c.moveToFirst();
    String lista = "";
    if(c.getCount() > 0) {
        while(true) {
           list.add(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("nome")).toString());
            if(!c.moveToNext()) break;
        }
    }

    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, list);

    user.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use `requery()` you can simply pass a new Cursor with the same query:

```
tasksCursor.close();
tasksCursor = schemaHelper.getTasks();
startManagingCursor(tasksCursor);
tasksAdapter.changeCursor(tasksCursor);
```

---

I assume that when you call `addTask()` you have already called `populateListView()` once. Try changing `addTask()` to this:

```
private void addTask(String description)
{
    String message = "";

    schemaHelper.open();

    if(schemaHelper.isAlreadyInDatabase(description))
    {
        message = getString(R.string.task_already_exists);
    }
    else
    {
        message = getString(R.string.task_succesfully_added);

        schemaHelper.insertTask(description);

        // Remove call to populateListView(), just update the Cursor 
        tasksCursor.close();
        tasksCursor = schemaHelper.getTasks();
        startManagingCursor(tasksCursor);
        tasksAdapter.changeCursor(tasksCursor);

        newTask.setText("");
    }

    schemaHelper.close();

    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

If this "doesn't work", please be more specific. Is it throwing an error, if so what kind?

---

You are doing a little too much work in your adapter. Please watch Android's Romain Guy at Google Talks discuss [adapters and `getView()`](http://www.google.com/events/io/2009/sessions/TurboChargeUiAndroidFast.html). However since you only want to pass one special string to your `createdOn` TextView, let's do something very different and override `setViewText()`:

Try this:

```
public class TasksAdapter extends SimpleCursorAdapter {
    String prefix;
    public TasksAdapter(Context context, int layout, Cursor cursor, String[] from, int[] to) {
        super(context, layout, cursor, from, to);
        // This is constant so set it once and consider adding the space to the end of the String in strings.xml
        prefix = getString(R.string.added_on) + " ";
    }

    @Override
    public void setViewText(TextView v, String text) {
        if(v.getId() == R.id.lv_row_created_on)
            v.setText(prefix + TaskHelper.formatDateWithSuffix(text));
        else
            super.setViewText(v, text);
    }
}
```

The rest of the data is taken care of with SimpleCursorAdapter's existing methods.

Comment: Cursor: Invalid statement in fillWindow(), and the ListView appears empty... and yes, when addTask() is called, populatelistView is already executed.

Comment: I see your database is closed before you read the Cursor, try moving `schemaHelper.open()` to `onResume()` and `schemaHelper.close()` to `onPause()`.

Comment: Still throwing the same error... could be an issue related to opening/closing the cursor?

Comment: Yes, good point. I updated my answer explicitly closing the first Cursor. Hope this helps.

Comment: mmm, now throws a different error: bad request for field slot 0 0. num_rows = 0 numcolumns = 0, this error points to the adapter...

Comment: I've uploaded the code above, the error appears at the adapter class, at "cursor.moveToPosition(position);"